# Initializing Array in Eiffel

Tags: arrays, dictionary, instance, eiffel

```
class
    MAP[G]
create
    make

feature --attributes
    g_array: ARRAY[G]
    size:INTEGER

feature{NONE}
make
    do
        g_array.make_empty
           size:=0
    end
```

---

```
class
    MAP_TESTING

m: MAP[INTEGER]

create m.make
print(m.size)
```

The first class consist of an array and its size. When I tried to create an `m` object of ARRAY, nothing seems to be printing out when I put `print(m.size)`. Am I instantiating the array correctly? Am I using the correct `make` function for `ARRAY`? Why isn't it printing anything?

### ---------------------------

```
class
    MAP[G]
create
    make

feature --attributes
    g_array: ARRAY[G]
    size:INTEGER

feature{NONE}
make
  --I left this blank
    end
```

---

```
class
    MAP_TESTING

m: MAP[INTEGER]

create m.make
print(m.size)
```

This actually works when I left the `make` blank. It prints out `0`. But this is no good because obviously if I call other functions using the array in `MAP`, it won't work. I actually tried using other functions from the class ARRAY, but I got a compile error.

Comment: The code with `g_array.make_empty` triggers an exception `Feature call on void target` because `g_array` is not initialized. Therefore `print` statement is not executed at all. Correct code would replace the feature call on `g_array` with the creation instruction on `g_array` that would create an array object and then execute `make_empty` on it.

Answer (score 2):

The line to create the array in `MAP` should be:

```
create g_array.make_empty
```

And `MAP_TESTING` should be:

```
class
    MAP_TESTING
creation
    make
feature
    m: MAP[INTEGER]

    make
    do
        create m.make
        print(m.size)
    end
end
```

(Note that the `print` does not output a newline so the zero may easily be lost in the terminal.)